# How can I break an array in shell script?

Tags: arrays, shell

I have a string and want to break an array but I'm not able to break.

```
#!/bin/bash
    KL=("GGJSTKR 10MG TkBS" "MAVICAL 10.8G PAWDER FR ORAL SALN SANHGT" "SDLPADLL 580TG/39MG CAPLETS" "AKHAC 1KL KYS RJOPS")

    IFS=' ' read -a TEST_ARR <<< "$KL"

    echo ${TEST_ARR[1]}

    Output

    10MG

The output should be like this

"GGJSTKR 10MG TkBS"
```

For example:-

```
"GGJSTKR 10MG TkBS" "MAVICAL 10.8G PAWDER FR ORAL SALN SANHGT" "SDLPADLL 580TG/39MG CAPLETS" "AKHAC 1KL KYS RJOPS"
```

My aim is to achieve like this

```
${TEST_ARR[0]}="GGJSTKR 10MG TkBS"
${TEST_ARR[1]}="MAVICAL 13.8G PAWDER FR ORAL SALN SANHGT"
${TEST_ARR[2]}="SDLPADLL 580TG/39MG CAPLETS"
${TEST_ARR[3]}="AKHAC 1KL KYS RJOPS"
```

Comment: You first line is not a valid shell syntax. What do you get when you do: `cat -vte <<< "$KL"`?

Comment: Actually, the quotes are not part of KL, so the blank between TkBS and MAVICAL is indistinguishable from the blank between MAVICAL and 10.8G.

Comment: thnkx anubhava@u r right now I have updated plz check

Comment: Use some other separator than whitespace and change your `IFS=` to the new separator

Comment: You don't need to use `read` as `KL` is already an array now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't just use KL, but I believe you are looking for:

```
TEST_ARR=("${KL[@]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using `read -a` then I think that this is what you are after:

```
#!/bin/bash

KL=("GGJSTKR 10MG TkBS" "MAVICAL 10.8G PAWDER FR ORAL SALN SANHGT" "SDLPADLL 580TG/39MG CAPLETS" "AKHAC 1KL KYS RJOPS")

IFS='"' read -a TEST_ARR <<< "${KL[*]}"

echo ${TEST_ARR[0]}
```